# Template view property points to parent view

Tags: ember.js

I have a container view into which i insert components dynamically.
When trying to access properties in that components template i've discovered that the template context is not the component but the container view, for some reason. Meaning that "view" property in template is not pointing to the component but to the container view above it.
Can't find any documentation that indicates that this is supposed to happen, so any ideas as to why this is happening?

Answer (score 0):

So, i got this to work.

What i did was override the _yield method in the component:

```
_yield: function () {
    return Ember.View.prototype._yield.apply(this, arguments);
}
```

Not sure why this is needed so if someone can enlighten me, please do so